# How to to design a PCB lib for components with variable dimensions?

Tags: pcb-design, design, layout, pad

I'm designing various PCB libraries for components. But sometimes they have variable dimensions:

[image]

How should I design the pads for components with fluctuating values?

Comment: Firstly, those are standard resistor sizes, so most software comes with libraries containing those.
Secondly, if you are trying to make new libraries, you will need to say what software you want to use them with.

Comment: @JackB I just want to design the pads

Comment: You would design three different footprints, one for each size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assume a worst-case scenario for each dimension (usually that means the largest dim), then you'll be safe as long as the manufacturer stays within their reported tolerance.

As Jack B mentioned in a comment, the example you gave is for standard resistor sizes so it's a poor example. But, assuming there wasn't a library for them in whatever software you use, you could design the 0603 footprint as 1.7x0.9x0.5